# DataGridView with Button Control - Delete Row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I want a Delete button at the end of each row of `DataGridView` and by clicking that I want to remove the desired row from the binding list which is data source of my grid.

But I can't seem to do it I have created a button object in product class and instantiated it with the unique id to remove that object from list. but button is not showing in the row.

[image: Screen shot]

There are TextBoxes in the form and users can enter text, and when they press Add button, a new object of product is instantiated with the provided fields and then it is added to the `BindingList`.

Finally this list is bound to the `DataGridView` and details are shown in the grid. (I have done this part).

and at last by clicking save button the list is saved in the DB.

```
public class Product{
    public string Brand { get; set; }   
    public int ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public product(string brand,int productPrice, int quantity){   
        this.Brand = brand;
        this.ProductPrice = productPrice;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }   
}

public partial class MainForm: Form{
    .....
    BindingList<Product> lProd = new BindingList<Product>();
    private void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        string Brand = txtProBrand.Text;
        int Price = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);
        int Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);

        Product pro = new Product(Brand, Price, Quantity);
        lProd.Add(pro);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = lProd;
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: I think this has been answered before.
stackoverflow.com/questions/21191950/how-to-add-a-button-to-a-column-in-the-datagridview

Comment: i can't seem to do it in a list. i can add a button to datatable. how to do that in the list??

Comment: If by list you mean your bindinglist then the answer is that you don't want to do that :) Your grid is bound to your Bindinglist of T, and the columns reflect the properties in your object of type T, and you don't want a "delete" property in your object - wich doesn't make much sense. Bind the datagridviwe to your list (like before) and then manually add a column with a delete-button, like this answer suggests.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To show a button on `DataGridView` rows, you should add a [`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to columns of your grid. Here is some common tasks which you should know when using button column:

- Add Button Column to DataGridView
- Show Image on Button
- Set Text of Button
- Handle Click Event of Button

**Add Button Column to DataGridView**

To show a button on each row of your grid, you can add a [`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to columns of your grid programmatically or using designer:

```
var deleteButton=new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
deleteButton.Name="dataGridViewDeleteButton";
deleteButton.HeaderText="Delete";
deleteButton.Text="Delete";
deleteButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue=true;
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(deleteButton);
```

**Show Image on Button**

If you prefer to draw image on button, you should have an image in a resource and then handle [`CellPainting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of your grid:

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["dataGridViewDeleteButton"].Index)
    {
        var image = Properties.Resources.DeleteImage; //An image
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);
        var x = e.CellBounds.Left + (e.CellBounds.Width - image.Width) / 2;
        var y = e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - image.Height) / 2;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new Point(x, y));

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Set Text of Button**

You can use either of these options:

You can set `Text` property of your `DataGridViewButtonColumn` and also set its `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` to `true`, this way the text will display on each cells of that column.

```
deleteButton.Text="Delete";
deleteButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue=true;
```

Also you can use `Value` property of cell:

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "Some Text";
```

Also as another option, you can handle [`CellFormatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of your grid. This way may be useful when you want to set different texts for buttons.

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //If this is header row or new row, do nothing
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        return;

    //If formatting your desired column, set the value
    if (e.ColumnIndex=this.dataGridView1.Columns["dataGridViewDeleteButton"].Index)
    {
        e.Value = "Delete";
    }
}
```

**Handle Click Event of Button**

To hanlde clicks on button, you can handle [`CellClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) or [`CellContentClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of your grid. Both events fires by click and by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

```
void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //if click is on new row or header row
    if( e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    //Check if click is on specific column 
    if( e.ColumnIndex  == dataGridView1.Columns["dataGridViewDeleteButton"].Index)
    {
        //Put some logic here, for example to remove row from your binding list.
        //yourBindingList.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);

        // Or
        // var data = (Product)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        // do something 
    }
}
```

**Get data of the record on Click event**

You have `e.RowIndex`, then you can get the data behind the row:

```
 var data = (Product)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
// then you can get data.Id, data.Name, data.Price, ...
```

You need to cast it to the data type of the recore, for example let's say `Product`.

If the data binding has been setup to use a DataTable, the the type to cast is `DataRowView`.

You can also use `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[some cell index].Value` to get value of a specific cell, however `DataBoundItem` makes more sense.

**Note**

- As mentioned by [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) in comments, when you use `BindingList` you don't need to set datasource of grid to null and back to binding list with every change. The `BindingList` itself reflects changes to your `DataGridView`.

Comment: Hi Reza. I was going to answer this, but noticed you already did. Could you include in your answer advice to remove the lines that set DataSource to null and then to binding list on every add to the binding list. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment Ivan, feel free to edit my answer and make it more useful :)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not so good in explanations like you :-) The code I mentioned, in addition of being redundant and inefficient, will require OP to recreate the column in question in case AutoGenerateColumns is true, which I bet is.