# How to Delete a Row with the Delete Column button in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Column Button Named "Delete", i want just Delete button to remove its row. i am Using this Event and it is working but the problem is i can remove row by clicking any column of DataGridView.

```
private void metroGrid1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int row = metroGrid1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    metroGrid1.Rows.RemoveAt(row);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the button is in every cell?

Comment: yes delete button is in each row and it is working but problem as i click like To Date cell it deletes the row

Comment: Just add a criteria to check if the clicked cell is the one that you want. For example `if(e.ColumnIndex == 2) { /* delete */ }`. Also to prevent error, you need to check `if( e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex || e.RowIndex < 0) return;`. To see an example take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33543430/3110834).

Comment: Why don't you have an event handler specific to the delete button then?  Having a generic "click anything" handler then forces you to figure out what was clicked.  Seems like more work for no gain to me.