# DataGridView row button text not appearing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I have a `DataGridView` control which looks like the following at design time:

[image]

Properties:

[image]

Then, at run-time, that DataGridView is populated as follows:

```
foreach (Word c in items)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add((i+1).ToString(), c.GroupNo, c.Name, c.CorrectnessCount);

    ... ... ...
    ... ... ...
    ... ... ...
 }
```

And, each row-button's click event is handled as follows:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
            e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            //TODO - Button Clicked - Execute Code Here
            btnEdit_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Now, can you spot the issue in the output?

Thre should be `Play` written in the foreground of each button. The buttons have no text in their caption area.

**How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: [DataGridView with Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549704/3110834)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` of DataGridViewButtonColumn to `true`. designer screen shows that it is `false`