# Buttons in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview

I am a beginner and I meet a problem with the Buttons in a DataGridView.

When I fill a cell with text that is the row number of the grid, no problem, the text is correct and stay correct if I add a new line.

But if I put this same text on the Button, all the lines are repainted and all the Buttons have the text of the last Button created.

My code is in the click event of a Button out the DataGridView:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
    textBox1.Text += "ligne clické " + e.RowIndex+ Environment.NewLine;
    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText( "bouton clické  "+btn.Tag+ Environment.NewLine) ;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] row;
    row = new string[] { "", "Product "+dataGridView1.RowCount };            
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
    btn.HeaderText = "Click Data";           
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int RND = rnd.Next(1, 1003);
    btn.Text = "Click Here"+dataGridView1.RowCount+" " + RND.ToString(); 
    btn.Name = "btn"+RND.ToString();
    btn.Tag = "tag ->" + dataGridView1.RowCount;
    btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more code?  I presume this is called in a loop, and maybe you have closures involved?  Specifically I don't see the `btn` declaration.

Comment: Are you using WPF? In that case can you provide some XAML code please.

Comment: It's a win form

Comment: i edited my my post to sholw the full code

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to do. Obviously, the variable `btn` (which you conveniently do not show its definition), is a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. In the `button1_Click` event, any “property” set on the `btn` variable, like… `btn.Text = "Click Here"+dataGridView1.RowCount+" " + RND.ToString();` …. is going to apply to the “WHOLE” column of buttons. I am not sure why you would expect otherwise. You will help yourself and others if you clarify what you want this “button” column to do and what text you want it to display.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549704/3110834

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        btn.HeaderText = "Click Data";
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int RND = rnd.Next(1, 1003);
        btn.Text = "Click Here" + dataGridView1.RowCount + " " + RND.ToString();
        btn.Name = "btn" + RND.ToString();
        btn.Tag = "tag ->" + dataGridView1.RowCount;
        int rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(btn);

        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = btn.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = "Product " + dataGridView1.RowCount;



    }
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54817181/edit) your question to add information. Don't post code as an answer unless it actually answers the question.