# How to assign list<object> to dataGridView and get single object when select row in c# and winForm?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, datagridview

I have a DGV **(DataGridView)**, I want set **list of Picture** have a **(ID, Caption, Price)** Property but show in DGV only  *Caption and Picture* andm, when select row on DGV get single object or get ID

**Example**

**List of Picture**

```
var data = new List<Picture>()
{
     new Picture(){ ID = 1, Caption = "A", Price = 5},
     new Picture(){ ID = 2, Caption = "B", Price = 2},
     new Picture(){ ID = 3, Caption = "C", Price = 8},
     new Picture(){ ID = 4, Caption = "D", Price = 6}
};
```

---

**DataGridView**

I want show data on DGV like this:

```
Caption   Price
------    ------
A          5
B          2
C          8
D          6
```

> I want when select row 1, find ID 1, row  2 find ID 2 **and so on ...**

**Use This code**

```
var data = new List<Picture>()
        {
            new Picture(){ ID = 1, Caption = "A", Price = 5},
            new Picture(){ ID = 2, Caption = "B", Price = 2},
            new Picture(){ ID = 3, Caption = "C", Price = 8},
            new Picture(){ ID = 4, Caption = "D", Price = 6}
        };

        dataGridView.DataSource = new BindingSource
        {
            DataSource = data
        };
```

Comment: It seems you have bound your data, is this working? What have you tried so far in getting respected record depending on the row you're on, it's possible you could have many rows selected?

Comment: Set `dataGridView.Columns["ID"].Visible = false` or in your `Picture` class, set `[Browsable(false)]` attribute for `ID`.

Comment: Need to support [DataAnnotations attributes for DataGridView in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885956/3110834) to control Column header texts, Order of columns, Tooltip, Format of columns?

Comment: If you set the `[Browsable(false)]` attribute, in the, say, `RowEnter` event, you can read the underlying data object: e.g. `var rowData = ([DataGridView].DataSource as BindingSource)[e.RowIndex] as Picture;`. If you just need the ID property because you can access the DataSource object directly, then simply hide the Column. It depends on how DataBindings work/are set up in your app.

Comment: Thanks  Reza Aghaei , use your suggestion nice idea

Comment: @JohnG You cannot make `Id` private because you need in in business logic for delete or update of the records. This is where you need `[Browsable(false)]`, the same for display name, let's say we had a requirement to show `Product Code` as column header text for the `Id` column in `DataGridView`, then do you want to change the `Id` property name to  `Product Code`, no you should not and you cannot. You need to use `[DisplayName("Product Code")]` attribute or use `Display` attribute for the property. Look at the linked post which I shared in my comment above. You will find it interesting.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei… After looking at my comment…, it only proves that I am tired and confused… it gets easier to get that way the older I get. I agree making the “ID” private is not a good idea and will not work in that scenario. I will delete the comment soon. Thanks for pointing this out and the post you supplied. 

Comment: @JohnG no worries, it happens when sleepy or tired 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem fixed by use new way

1. Use add column ID but **Visible = false** [image: ID_Hidden]
2. Use **dataGridView_CellClick** event handler to get id

**Assign Object to DGV**

```
foreach (var item in PictureAPI.GET())
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(item.ID, item.Caption, item.Price);
```

**Get ID**

```
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get ID 
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);

        // Find Object
        var obj = PictureAPI.GET().First(A => A.ID == id);
    }
```

Comment: I see you want to have delete button on rows, so you will find this post useful: [DataGridView with Button Control - Delete Row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549704/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei  thanks you, use ID column hidden and fixed by use my this answer